# Get specific Version from Source control

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, controls, changeset

I have 34 word templates in TFS and I'm suing VS2012.
Only 32 have been modified and saved under a change set.
I wanted to just extract those modified by that change set.
I made sure my mapped folder was empty before I started.
I used Advanced/Get Specific and then did a get using the changeset number
However, all 34 templates were downloaded into my folder.
The changeset get seems to get all files modified before and up to the change set I requested.
In my case I can pick out the 2 files and remove them.  But if I had hundreds of files spread over a dozen folder it would be a nightmare.
Is there a way to get only those files modified by a specific changeset files ?

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Get Specific" means getting **all** the files as how they were at the time when ChangeSet was created. It doesn't mean getting only changed files.

Since you are using VS 2012, you could use [Team Foundation Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2012Power)' `tfpt GetCS` command:

> The **GetCS** tool retrieves all items listed in a changeset for a
> given changeset version.
>
> This is useful when a co-worker checks in a change that you need to
> have in your workspace, but you cannot upgrade your entire workspace
> to the latest version. Use the **GetCS** tool to get just the items
> affected by your co-worker’s changeset. You can do this without
> inspecting the changeset to manually list the changed files when using
> a **getcs** command.
>
> There is no graphical user interface for the **GetCS** tool. To invoke
> the **GetCS**, type the following command. The parameter
> *changesetnum* specifies the changeset number.
>
> `tfpt GetCS /changeset:changesetnum`